# How to order data based on the relative lag between two fields?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table containing id, dates, old_values, and new_values. This table was created such that the old_value in the current row corresponds to the new_value from the previous row. However, the date field is often duplicated, such that the old_values and new_values do not correspond to one another. How can I order this data such that for each id, the old_value matches the new_value from the previous row?

For instance...

| id | index | date | old_value | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 1/1/23 | A | B |
| A1 | 2 | 1/2/23 | C | D |
| A1 | 3 | 1/2/23 | D | E |
| A1 | 4 | 1/2/23 | B | C |
| A1 | 5 | 1/3/23 | E | F |
| A1 | 6 | 1/4/23 | F | D |
| A2 | 7 | 1/2/23 | G | A |
| A2 | 8 | 1/3/23 | W | C |
| A2 | 9 | 1/3/23 | A | W |
| A2 | 12 | 1/3/23 | C | Z |
| A2 | 13 | 1/4/23 | Z | A |

...should be reordered by index, such that the date order is preserved, and the order within each date is such that each old_value is equal to the new_value of the previous row. In this case, the resulting table should look like the following:

| id | index | date | old_value | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 1/1/23 | A | B |
| A1 | 4 | 1/2/23 | B | C |
| A1 | 2 | 1/2/23 | C | D |
| A1 | 3 | 1/2/23 | D | E |
| A1 | 5 | 1/3/23 | E | F |
| A1 | 6 | 1/4/23 | F | D |
| A2 | 7 | 1/2/23 | G | A |
| A2 | 9 | 1/3/23 | A | W |
| A2 | 8 | 1/3/23 | W | C |
| A2 | 10 | 1/3/23 | C | Z |
| A2 | 11 | 1/4/23 | Z | A |

I don't have a strong idea of how to approach this, so any advice would be welcomed. I am using an Oracle DBMS.

Edit: I have modified the example table with id=A2 to clarify my question. Whereas A1 can also be satisfied by sorting alphabetically, A2 can not. When A2 is properly sorted (such that the old_value proceeds from the previous row's new_value), it is not in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a query that will walk through the data (hierarchical / recursive query), and from there you can define a new column to order by (the level in the recursion).

[https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/queries003.htm#:~:text=CONNECT%20BY%20specifies%20the%20relationship,which%20rows%20contain%20the%20loop](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/queries003.htm#:%7E:text=CONNECT%20BY%20specifies%20the%20relationship,which%20rows%20contain%20the%20loop).

```
SELECT
   id, index, date, old_value, new_value, LEVEL
FROM
   your_table
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR new_value = old_value
   AND PRIOR id        = id
   AND PRIOR date      = date
START WITH
   NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
        FROM your_table
       WHERE id = d.id
         AND date = d.date
         AND new_value = d.old_value
   )
ORDER BY
   id, date, LEVEL
;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/j1epC3SC

Comment: These recursive functions are new to me, but could be close to something like what I'm going for. To affirm some of your comments in the other thread: "it's not the old value that's 'wrong', it's the index". That is correct. In my situation, the index should be reordered to reflect reality: that the old_value logically follows from the previous row's new_value. Appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: I will review this answer more in depth during the workday tomorrow and check it if it leads to a solution.

Comment: There is no need to use recursion here.

Comment: @PaulW There objectively is. A row's position is determined by the preceding row's position. The old values and new values are not necessarily in sortable order, as shown in the final row when the value transitions from F to D and still comes last.

Comment: @DylanMoore I made a small correction by adding the date to the connect by. That helps prevent misordering of the value sequence returns to an old value; ABCDEFDFDF. But, that won't help if such 'repetition' ocures on the same date.

Comment: @MatBailie, I have edited my question to include a second test case, for clarity. I apologize for the lack of clarity in my first test case. Curious if you could provide feedback.

Comment: @DylanMoore my existing answer should cater for that, without alteration. Have you tried it?

Comment: I am working through applying this solution to my use case now. Currently dealing with some suspiciously long query times and "ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data" errors.

Comment: @DylanMoore - thank you for our back-and-forth under my answer that clarified your needs. I believe I did not understand what you were after, and that in fact MatBalie did. Therefore I agree with his answer, you must use recursion. I'll restore the downvote on his answer.

Comment: I was able to produce results with this query by adding "CONNECT BY NOCYCLE" (receiving ORA-01436 otherwise). I'm unsure whether this change produces the following bug: The results are close. However, for results at LEVEL 2 or 3, the row is duplicated at lower levels (i.e. LEVEL 1 and 2). If I somehow took the max(LEVEL) per duplicate, the results would be ordered correctly. Is there a clean way to remove the lower levels, such that no results are duplicated?

Comment: @DylanMoore Apologies, I didn't include a START WITH clause for where the recursion should begin, so, it begins everywhere simultaneously. I've corrected the answer and added a demo including the case where it still fails (cycles in the same date).